# Correlate database calls with incoming HTTP request using TypeORM and node.js/Hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, typeorm

I'm using TypeOrm (SQL Server) and hapi.js. I've created a [custom logger](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md) and would like to log a pre-existing correlation ID when I log information about the query. The correlation ID is currently set on a request header in the incoming request. The docs show an example where request information can be obtained on the `data` property of the query runner, but that property is not being set with the SQL server provider.

How can I get access to the current request headers from within my custom Type ORM logger?